# Jackson serializing: Get list of processed objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

For a special case, I need to know which "source objects" of the object tree Jackson processed during serialization.

```
public class A {}

public class B {
   private A a;
}

public class Main {
   public void doIt() {
      B b = new B();
      b.a = new A();
      m.writeValueAsString(b)

      // Here I need to get the list of all processed objects from mapper m, i.e. [a,b]
   }
}
```

I think there is some internal list, because Jackson might reuse already serialized objects if they are referenced multiple times in the object tree. Can I get this list? Or is it possible to build my own list by an event listener which is called for every serialized object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with a `PropertyFilter`. I'm collecting all the objects seen in `serializeAsField` and at the end I've a complete list of traversed objects.